# Finding YouTube users using Data API v3

Tags: youtube-api

Given a name (eg John Doe) I'm looking for ways to search for users using the API. I can only find how to search for videos, channels etc.

Any tip?

Rolf

Answer (score 0):

You can't search for users, but if you want to search channels with old usernames you can use the [channels.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list) with [forUsername](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list#forUsername) parameter.